# Data collector 'Code Coverage' failed to provide initialization information

Tags: unit-testing, build, code-coverage, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to create a code coverage report using the Build pipeline. 
I have added the task of type`Visual Studio code` in the build pipeline and have enabled the Code Coverage.

When the build is triggered. I'm getting :

```
Data collector 'Code Coverage' message: Data collector 'Code Coverage' failed to provide initialization information. Error: System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Diagnostics.Logging.ProfilerInterop' threw an exception. ---> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Diagnostics.Common.InvariantException: Failed to load IntelliTrace Profiler binary or failed to locate functions.
```

and

```
---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The system cannot find the path specified
```

This is running the tests and all the tests are passed. However I'm not able to view the code coverage report. The report which it has created contains only information about the tests

Any input on where we specify the path will be useful.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58844234/2157640

Answer (score 23):

You basically need **Visual Studio Test Agent** for Code Coverage.

There are 2 possible ways to install for this:

- **Option 1**

  1. Install `Agents for Visual Studio 2019` on the Build server (download from [here](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/), see under *Tools for Visual Studio 2019*).
  2. In the build pipeline edit the `Visual Studio Test Assemblies` task. Set `Select test platform using` to `Specific location` and set `Path to vstest.console.exe` to for example `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\TestAgent\Common7\IDE\Extensions\TestPlatform\vstest.console.exe`.
- **Option 2**

  1. Add the `Visual Studio test platform installer` build task to your pipeline. (Add this task before the testing task).
  2. In the `Visual Studio Test Assemblies` task you have to select `Installed by Tools Installer` as the `Test platform version`

**Note:** in my experience I had some tests who succeeded with option 1, but failed in option2. Sadly I don't have the time to figure out why...

Comment: Option 1 worked for me, Option 2 did not.  Thank you!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer @Dev. Option 2 worked for me.

Comment: Great Answer, both options worked for me - going with Option 1 because of your Note.

Answer (score 1):

I faced this issue when configuring a build container.

## 1 To install the Visual Studio 2019 Test Agent, I used [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/)

### 1.2 Install Chocolatey

ENV chocolateyUseWindowsCompression = false

```
SHELL ["powershell.exe", "-ExecutionPolicy", "Bypass", "-Command"]
RUN Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force; iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1')); `
    [System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('PATH', "\"${env:PATH};%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\chocolatey\bin\"", 'Machine'); `
    choco feature enable -n allowGlobalConfirmation;
```

### 1.2 Install the TestAgent with chocolatey

```
RUN choco install visualstudio2019testagent -y
```

## 2. Edit the [VSTest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/test/vstest?view=azure-devops) task on your pipeline to use a specific location.

In my case, I've installed into the container the VSBuildTools. The VSTest task used the VSBuildTools `vstest.console.exe` but the execution needs some libraries that are located at the `TestAgent` folders.

```
vstestLocationMethod: location
vstestLocation: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\TestAgent\Common7\IDE\Extensions\TestPlatform\vstest.console.exe'
```

Answer (score -3):

Had a similar problem after updating build agent and adding VS2017 capabilities.

Downloaded (from https://www.opendll.com):  microsoft.intellitrace.profiler.dll

Add to folder C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\Common7\IDE\Extensions\TestPlatform\x64​

Good luck